# Location field not accessible when using the UseBulkAPI connection option in the CData Salesforce ODBC Driver

Tags: salesforce, cdata-drivers

We are using the CData Drivers to retrieve the Data from the Location Object in Salesforce. When we set the UseBulkAPI connection option to True in CData, the Location field in the Location Object is not accessible. If we set the UseBulkAPI connection option to False, the Location field in the Location object is accessible.

Please advise.

Location Object and the Location field is a standard object in Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

The Bulk API [does not support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm) compound fields, including geolocation fields and address fields:

> Also, Bulk API can’t access or query compound address or compound geolocation fields.

You can't use the Bulk API with these fields. Your client may or may not be able to work around this limitation by directly accessing the constituent fields of a compound field.

Comment: David, correct. I understand that the Location field may be a compound field, but the way that the CData Drivers handle compound fields is that it expands field into multiple fields. So my question is why CData is not able to handle this field? Is it a bug in the CData Driver?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that product, but I personally would describe it as a bug yes.